# Adding constraint at sql level to copy column

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a table to store parameter names

```
CREATE TABLE PARAM_NAMES
{

PARAM_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PARAM_NAME" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 

"DEFAULT_VALUE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 

 CONSTRAINT "PARAMS_UK1" UNIQUE ("PARAM_TYPE_ID")
//PARAM_TYPE ID is the primary key
}
```

I have other table to store parameter values,

```
CREATE TABLE PARAM_VALUES" 
   {    "ID"  NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PARAM_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PARAM_VALUE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 

     CONSTRAINT "PARAM_VALUES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID", "PARAM_TYPE_ID")
}
```

For a particular parameter name with param Id i am using ParamId to store parameter value in the other table.

Now I am using JDBC to get and set values to the table.Now I want to do some thing like this.

While inserting param value from JDBC i want to insert DEFAULT_VALUE  if paramvalue is null or empty ie if someone inserts null value or empty value from JDBC i want to copy default value from PARAM_NAMES table to PARAM_VALUES  table PARAM_VALUE column.Anything i can do at sql level or constraint level?I know i can do in java before inserting check whether null if not copy default value but want to know anything at sql level.

```
PARAM_TYPE_ID   PARAM_NAME           DEFAULT_VALUE
1                  ABC                 TEST1
2                  CDE                 TEST2
3                  FGH                 TEST3


PARAM_TYPE_ID     PARAM_VALUE
1                   TEST4       //Since not null
2                    TEST2      //since null default value is copied
3                   TEST3         //since null default value is copied
```

Comment: Can the default value be changed, and if so, would you want that updated value to apply to all defaulted `PARAM_VALUES` entries?

Comment: Default values will not change.But particular default values will be updated against  particular param_type_id

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
create table abc (
field1 varchar(10) default 'fred'
```

However, I would use my application code to do things like forcing empty strings to the default value.  With character fields you might end up storing empty strings and with numeric fields you might end up throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do this with a trigger?  This would allow you to enforce your business rule regardless of the process that is inserting data.  This will also handle updates and the case where the param_type_id is not found in the param_names table.

```
create or replace trigger trg_param_values 
before insert or update on param_values 
for each row
begin
  select default_value into :new.param_value
  from param_names
  where param_names.param_type_id = :new.param_type_id
  ;
exception
when others then
  :new.param_value := 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE'; 
end
;
```